# How to read series of flatbuffers from file with Java

Tags: java, file-io, flatbuffers

From a previous question, I wrote a series of size prefixed flatbuffer data to a file using Python. In Python, I can get the data back by reading 4 bytes to get the size of the next data piece and then reading in that many bytes to get the data and repeating this until EOF. No big deal. Now, I am trying to read that data back in Java. I have a method within a class that loads the data file, grabs the first four bytes, decodes that to an integer, and then uses that to read in the data since the first four bytes should be the data size. Here is an example:

```
public class Flatbuffer_IO{
    File inFile;
    RandomAccessFile f;



    public void load_data_file(String file) throws IOException{
        inFile = new File(file);
        f = new RandomAccessFile(inFile, "r");      
        byte[] prefix = new byte[4];
        f.readFully(prefix);
        int dataSize = ByteBufferUtil.getSizePrefix(ByteBuffer.wrap(prefix));
        byte data[] = new byte[dataSize];
        f.readFully(data);          
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);     
        .
        .
        .
```

What happens is the dataSize ends up being a really large number, larger than the whole file size, let alone one data piece. I changed readFully() to just read() and looked at the size of the data being read and it reads in the entire file, minus 4 bytes since I already grabbed that for the data size. I went back to Python with the exact same file, and my dataSize is correct in that it is only the size of the next data piece. Does Java read the first four bytes differently somehow?

Comment: Have you checked big-endian vs. little-endian in your reading and writing those four bytes?  I'll bet that Python thinks that writing the number 0x00000123 writes it as 23, 01, 00, 00, and your getSizePrefix is making the number 0x23010000 from it.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you so much!